# Determining length and start of a spell of daily consecutive observations of 1 from unstacked data - pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, time-series

I am trying to determine the length of spells with consecutive observations of `1`. The data is daily data and grouped by `year` and `id`.

See the dataframe below, which in column `conseq` reports values of `1` if some condition is met.

Now, I am only interested in the rows that form a distinctive spell of constitutive observations. The spell should be at least three days long.

For example, in the frame below there is long spell of values of `conseq` from 7 July to 13 July. From that spell I am interested in retrieving the length (7), and the starting point (7 July).

The desired output would be what the column: `how_to_get_this_column` shows.

There are about a million of these rows for many years and many `id`s.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO, BytesIO

data = ('year,id,date,conseq,how_to_get_this_column\n'
'1991,X000005010,1991-08-09,0,0\n'
'1991,X000005010,1991-08-11,0,1\n'
'1991,X000005010,1991-08-12,1,1\n'
'1991,X000005901,1991-07-07,0,7\n'
'1991,X000005901,1991-07-08,1,7\n'
'1991,X000005901,1991-07-09,1,7\n'
'1991,X000005901,1991-07-10,1,7\n'
'1991,X000005901,1991-07-11,1,7\n'
'1991,X000005901,1991-07-12,1,7\n'
'1991,X000005901,1991-07-13,1,7\n'
'1991,X000005901,1991-08-07,0,0\n')
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data))
df.set_index(['id'], inplace=True)
```

Comment: What is the desired output for the data you showed

Comment: @Martien Lubberik rows range is chosen based on id or by months?

Comment: @Zaraki Kenpach: this is daily data ('date' column) for firms ('id'). The 'year' column is derived from the data, but not really relevant.